# how to generate junit reports using Behave

Tags: python, selenium, python-behave

I've tried to use console and configuration file to generate JUnit report - without any success. To be more precise, I get empty file `TESTS-features.forms.xml` in `reports` folder. I've tried to change default folder for reports - without any luck. There is also `pretty.output`, but it is log from console.

Here is screenshot:
[image]

My goal is to obtain reports that can be processed by some Jenkins plugin (like Cucumber Reports).

This is my behave.ini:

```
[behave]
junit=true
format=pretty
```

Perhaps someone can provide me working example, I'm talking about config file? Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

This bug is fixed in behave-1.2.5

Comment: The bug is fixed but [the verbose output does not properly indicate when junit is True](https://github.com/behave/behave/issues/365)